# How to join two tables on changed columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables in PostgreSQL:

```
A  (ida, ida2)
B  (idb, idb2)
```

all columns are `integer`. I need to join them in an non-standard join,  meaning that if ida2 is not null then the join is `on (ida2=idb2)` if it's null the join is `on (ida=idb)`

I need to use it in a view so I can not use `IF` statment. 
I thought of using `coalesce`, but it can only select 1 integer not 2.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW myview AS 
 SELECT .....
   FROM A 
   join B on .....? ;
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Something like `a join b on coalesce(a.ida2, a.ida) = coalesce(b.idb2, b.idb)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name What with case if ida2 is null and idb2 is not null? They compare ida with idb2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [UNION](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-union.html)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW myview AS 
 SELECT .....
   FROM A 
   join B on ida2 is not null and ida2 = idb2
 UNION
 SELECT .....
   FROM A 
   join B on ida2 is null and ida = idb
```